# I'm an animal (?)

Tags: riddle

I am an animal

Change a letter, I can save your life.

Take away a letter and scramble, I can make you powerful.

Add 2 letters, I can puzzle you.

What was I originally?

Comment: scramble at each step? Or on second step for instance are you only changing one letter in place?

Comment: Are these sequential, or do they all apply to the original word?

Comment: What was I originally? An animal!

Comment: What's my mistake? Please explain.

Comment: It's unclear how to apply the different steps. For example after the first step of changing a letter, do you have to take away a letter from and scramble the result of the first step or do you take the original word again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correct answer

> hound -> sound -> sudo -> sudoku

Yes, there's too little info in the riddle to solve it, and it's unclear whether the actions apply to the original word or they are sequential. This was 4 years ago, now I know better.

Answer (score 8):

Well,well,well...I think I've got this one...

> The answer is: DOG.

First it has been said "I am an animal."

> So DOG suffices.

"Change a letter, I can save your life."

> If we change G to C , we get DOC , and a doc (= doctor of course), can definitely save our lives...

Now...

> We take away D and scramble OC to get CO...which stands for C.O. , i.e. [Commanding Officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commanding_officer). Now that's what you call powerful.

Finally...

> We add the two letters D and E to CO ; we get CODE...that puzzles us.

So,Done, ain't it ? :) Guess it works fine.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this fits, but:

You are a

> Bear

If I change one of your letters, then I'll get

> BESR or BEIR (Both are acronyms for a committee that can "save your life") [this is the part where I feel it doesn't really fit...]

or I can change one of your letters to get

> Beer, but I don't see how this would save your life :P

If I remove one of those letters and scramble you, I'll have

> Reb, which is a respectful word that people may call you (to make you feel powerful)

Add two letters to that, and you'll get

> Rebus, which is certainly something that can puzzle me :)

I hope this works :)

Comment: "but I don't see how this would save your life" -> it makes life worth living! :-D